# left outer join with null values

Tags: sql, oracle

```
**Table1**                  **Table2**    

ID       Values           ID         Values
1        100              1          10
2        200              2          20
3        300              3          30
4        400              4          40
null     2000             null       3000
5        500
```

o/p:-

```
ID       Table1_Values  Table2_Values
1        100            10
2        200            20
3        300            30
4        400            40
5        500            null
null    2000            3000
```

Comment: Both table id column have multiple null value then what accepted result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this ..

```
select t1.id,t1.values,t2.values from
table1 t1 
left outer join
table t2 on nvl(t1.id,0)=nvl(t2.id,0)
```

Comment: select nvl(t1.id,0) id ,t1.values,t2.values from
table1 t1 , table t2  where t1.id   = t2.id(+)

Comment: What happens if there is an id of `0`? This would then join the rows where one is `NULL` and the other is `0` which would probably be in error.

Comment: @MT0. Correct. This is just work around, since `null` is not a value. So, we can't join the table on the basis of `null`. Depending the table value, we can change `0` to some other value.

Comment: `we can't join the table on the basis of null` - why not? Check if both ids are null and add that to the join condition (as per my answer) - it eliminates the need to find an unused value (which may then break the application if that value is later used without updating this select).

Comment: @MT0. I mean to say, we shouldn't. Because, considering your query and @Mukesh has mentioned in the comment of OP question. If we have multiple `null` value in the column, then which value would show ? Also, I would not say you are actually joining the tables rather you added condition there to match if columns from both tables has `null` value, which will fail in case of multiple `null` value (Even my query will fail). That's why I said, we can't join `null`. Since, `null` means nothing, it doesn't tell any value.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a check to see if both values are `NULL` to the join condition:

```
SELECT t1.ID,
       t1.VALUES AS Table1Values,
       t2.VALUES AS Table2Values
FROM   TABLE2 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       TABLE2 t2
       ON ( t1.ID = t2.ID OR ( t1.ID IS NULL AND t2.ID IS NULL ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an Oracle function Sys_Op_Map_NonNull that has been used for many versions as part of a materialised view refresh query for just this purpose.

https://oraclesponge.wordpress.com/2006/04/12/a-quick-materialized-view-performance-note/

It used to be entirely undocumented, but is now mentioned as a means of optimising fast refresh: http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DWHSG/basicmv.htm

So you could:

```
select ...
from   t1 left outer join t2 on (sys_op_map_nonnull(t1.id) = sys_op_map_nonnull(t2.id))
```

If you were joining a small set of the table then function-based indexes would help, but I wouldn't bother if you're joining all rows.