# LEFT JOIN WHERE Clause IS NOT NULL

Tags: sql

I have two tables A and B
Common column x

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON A.x == B.x
WHERE A.z == "Hola" AND B.y IS NOT NULL;
```

I'm confused as to what output this would produce compared to EXIST or a LEFT JOIN WHERE Clause is null.

If I'm not mistaken this takes What's on A and common between A&B, but excluding what B is null, correct?

Comment: This is like an inner join based on your where condition to exclude B null values.

Comment: If B value is not null, I think that it would be common atleast with table A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B
     ON A.x = B.x
WHERE A.z = 'Hola' AND B.y IS NOT NULL;
```

You need to decompose the query.

The result set will have only `A.Z = 'Hola'`.  That is an important filter in the `WHERE` clause.

Then, `B.y IS NOT NULL` means two things:  both that the match exists in `B` and that `y` is not `NULL`.  So, this query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A INNER JOIN
     B
     ON A.x = B.x
WHERE A.z = 'Hola' AND B.y IS NOT NULL;
```

With an inner join, you could put the `WHERE` conditions in the `ON`.  That is a matter of style.  You cannot do this with a `LEFT JOIN`.

Then, the "equivalent" `EXISTS` query would be:

```
SELECT A.*
FROM A 
WHERE A.z = 'Hola' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM B WHERE A.x = B.x AND B.y IS NOT NULL);
```

These are not exactly the same.  The version with `JOIN` will return duplicate rows for `A` if there are multiple matches in `B`.  Because you are only selecting from `A`, duplicates are probably not desirable, and I would recommend the `EXISTS` query.

Comment: Gordon thanks for the explanation! What if in cases where B is common to A, I want to assign specific B column values to A column values (Example: for filling empty content in A). Would this approach still work? I would like to mention duplicates in A as you mention.

Comment: @Vesper . . . New questions should be asked as *questions* not *comments.*  This question is clearly about `select` and not `update.

Answer (score 1):

If table contains following values:

```
**Table1**                  **Table2**    

ID       Values           ID         Values
1        100              1          10
2        200              2          20
3        300              3          30
4        400              4          40
null     2000             null       3000
5        500
```

Your query will return the following:

with: `A.Id, A.table1_values, B.Table2_values`

```
ID       Table1_Values  Table2_Values
1        100            10
2        200            20
3        300            30
4        400            40
5        500            null
```

Final output for `a.*`:

```
ID       Table1_Values  
1        100            
2        200            
3        300            
4        400            
5        500
null     2000
```

Copied data from here: [left outer join with null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31422466/left-outer-join-with-null-values)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, what do you mean final output for a.*?

Comment: @Vesper That's the query you posted: `SELECT A.*`

Answer (score 1):

Very simple but good question.

Let's make transformations and find answer

## Step 1: Move  `WHERE` predicate on `B.y` to `JOIN`-clause

```
SELECT 
    A.*
FROM 
    A
    LEFT JOIN B ON A.x == B.x
        AND B.y IS NOT NULL
WHERE 
    A.z == "Hola";
```

Now we can:

1. Transform `LEFT JOIN` into `UNION ALL` of `JOIN-` and `NOT EXISTS-` expressions

## Step 2: Transformation `LEFT JOIN` -> `JOIN` + `NOT EXISTS`

```
SELECT A.*
    FROM A
    JOIN B ON A.x == B.x
        AND B.y IS NOT NULL 
WHERE 
    A.z == "Hola" 
UNION ALL
SELECT A.*
    FROM A
WHERE 
    A.z == "Hola"
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM B 
            WHERE A.x = B.x                
            AND B.y IS NOT NULL
    )
```

Looking at this expressions we can see that:

1. In general case it could not be simplified more
2. In case when all fields of table B defined with not `NOT NULL` - lower part of `UNION ALL` becames redundant

Answer (score 0):

you may try something like this:

```
select a.*
from a
where a.z = "Hola"
and exists (select 1
            from b
            where b.y is not null
            and b.x = a.x);
```